# Show modal window on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am aware this question has been asked many times but I just cannot seem to get this to work because of my almost null JS knowledge.

I am using the [Zebra Dialog](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-dialog/) jquery plugin to make a modal window that I want to open when the page is loaded.

All the examples on the Zebra Dialog website only explain how to load the modal when clicking a link, but I just cannot seem to get it to load on page load.

I am using the following code right now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).load(function() {

    // show a dialog box when clicking on a link
    $(anchor).bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.Zebra_Dialog('The link was clicked!');
    });

 });

</script>
```

I am aware that I am using code for loading the modal when clicking on a link but I have tried a lot of stuff and not found a way to succesfully modify it to load on page load.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps jQuery is not included? You need jQuery, then the plugin js/css in your `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/zebra_dialog.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/zebra_dialog.css" type="text/css">
```

and then the the loading code in `<body>` (in script tags or loaded from a file)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.Zebra_Dialog('Page loaded!');
});
```

Comment: Yes I tried that too but it won´t work for some reason. Seeing everyone suggest this makes me think there might be some additional code that I need to use?

Comment: I updated the answer with some help regarding including files.

Comment: Sorry, just realized there is some other JS interfering with the Zebra Dialog. Your example worked

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).load(function() {

   $.Zebra_Dialog('The link was clicked!');

});
```

Comment: Yep, that´s one of the things I trid and it wouldn´t work. For some reason.

Answer (score 0):

i would try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.Zebra_Dialog('Page loaded!');
});
```

This basically means that once the document is ready (i.e. loaded), open your modal dialog.  Previously you had the code saying, when the document is ready attach a handler to the click event of some element (not sure what 'anchor' is in your code), and in that event handler open the dialog.

Comment: Yes I tried that too but it won´t work for some reason. Seeing everyone suggest this makes me think there might be some additional code that I need to use?

Comment: Sorry, just realized there is some other JS interfering with the Zebra Dialog. Thanks for the great explanation!